# Custom Magento Extension. How can I add the option to enable or disable it?

Tags: magento, module

I have finally got my first extension built thanks to everyone here! I managed to get the extension added as a tab in the admin area as well. I have a menu that says enable or disable. I would like to make this function work giving the customer more control with this extension. Before it is mentioned, I am aware that you can enable and disable extensions under the advanced menu. However, most Magento customers are not. I would like to add this directly to my extension.

If the module is enabled I would like to overide the shipping.phtml file located in the checkout/cart/shipping.phtml with my own custom shipping template.

1. How can I make my enable or disable dropdown box work? Below is my code:

etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <beckinconfig translate="label" module="dropdownshipping">
        <label>Beckin Extensions</label>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </beckinconfig>
</tabs> 
<sections>  
    <dropdownshipping translate="label" module="dropdownshipping">
        <label>Drop Down Shipping Options</label>
        <tab>beckinconfig</tab>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

        <groups>            
                  <general>
            <label>General</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>       
              <fields>
                            <enable translate="label">
                            <label>Enable</label>
                            <comment>
                            <![CDATA[Enable or Disable this extension.]]>
                            </comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                                 <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                            </enable>           
             </fields>                 
        </general>
        </groups>
    </dropdownshipping>
</sections>     
</config>
```

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
<modules>
<Beckin_DropDownShipping><version>1.0.0</version></Beckin_DropDownShipping>
    </modules>

<global>

            <blocks>
                 <beckin_dropdownshipping>
                      <class>Beckin_DropDownShipping_Block</class>
                 </beckin_dropdownshipping>
            </blocks>

    <helpers>
         <beckin_dropdownshipping>
         <class>Beckin_DropDownShipping_Helper</class>
         </beckin_dropdownshipping>
    </helpers>      
</global>

<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <beckin>
                <file><!-- beckin_dropdownshipping.xml --></file>
            </beckin>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <dropdownshipping>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Beckin_DropDownShipping</module>
                <frontName>dropdownshipping</frontName>
            </args>
        </dropdownshipping>
    </routers>  
</frontend>


<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <dropdownshipping_options>
                                        <title>Beckin Drop Down Shipping Extension</title>
                                    </dropdownshipping_options>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>

</config>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Beckin_DropDownShipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{   

}
```

Block/Cart/Shipping.php

```
<?php


class Beckin_DropDownShipping_Block_Cart_Shipping extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Shipping
{

protected function _construct()
{

      if(Mage::getStoreConfig('beckin/dropdownshipping_options/enable', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()){
     {
     $this->setTemplate('Beckin/dropdownshipping/drop_down_shipping.phtml');
     }
        else
        {
        $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart/shipping.phtml');
        }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help provided!! I am getting a blank admin page now when I go to the system/config section where my extension is located. I am sure it is something simple that I am missing. I have included every file above that I am using except for the template file which I believe is irrelevant. Can you spot my error? I wished it would show me an error instead of the page being blank :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without known exactly what your module does and where and how your loading it. Assuming that it is not a custom shipping extension. You could do

Eg. 1

```
if((Mage::getStoreConfig('deckin/dropdownshipping_options/beckin_enable', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()){
   module enable/display .phtml
   assuming that beckin_enable value are 0 or 1
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by '... the template xml file to set the template to override the shipping.phtml file ...'
`
You may need to find and rewrite the block construct that set the template file for the shipping

Eg. 2

```
protected function _construct()
{
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('deckin/dropdownshipping_options/beckin_enable', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()){
        $this->setTemplate('.../my_custom_shipping.phtml');
     }
     else{
        $this->setTemplate('.../regular_shipping.phtml');
     }
}
```

Also, You don't need to create you own 'source model' for yes/no, magento have it pre-built

```
<beckin_enable>
    ....
    <source_model>dropdownshipping/enable</source_model>                           
    ...                    
</beckin_enable>
```

You could have done

```
<beckin_enable>
    ....
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                          
    ...                    
</beckin_enable>
```

Comment: Thanks U. Just to clarify I am just wanting to override the cart shipping template if my module is enabled with my own template. I tried to follow your instructions but I am getting a blank admin page now when I go to the system/config section where my extension is located. I am sure it is something simple that I am missing. I have included every file above that I am using except for the template file which I believe is irrelevant. Can you spot my error? P.S. I did a little bit of editing to make it make more since. I wished it would show me an error instead of the page being blank :(

Comment: One thing that could cause a issue/ future issues is `<sections>  
    <beckin translate="label" module="dropdownshipping">` better if you do `<sections>  
    <dropdownshipping translate="label" module="dropdownshipping">`
This doesn't need any more `Model/Enable.php`. This not been use getCfgGeneral()

Comment: Also check your error log to see what error your getting. I dont see where you are rewriting this Block/Cart/Shipping.php, in your layout.xml are you using block `type='dropdownshipping/cart_shipping' instead?

Comment: Thank you again for your advice. I have changed my files according to what you said above. However, I am still getting a blank config page :( About the rewrite of the block. I did away with that. It was in the template layout.xml file since we are trying to make this function with the enable or disable. Can you see what is wrong with the code now? I am going to call my hosting company and find out why I am not seeing any error logs on my end. Thanks again for all the advice!

Comment: P.S. @R.S I removed the Model/Enable.php file like you said, updated the sections, and removed the function in the helper. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I setup Wamp Server so I can see my errors. This is what I am getting... Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Dropdownshipping_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\dev3\app\Mage.php on line 546 Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Double check `Beckin_DropDownShipping_Helper` `Helper/Data.php` it not finding it